# form validation in cakephp

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have one model `login` - it has 5 fields. At time of registration I am validating all the fields, but when I edit the record I want to validate only some fields before saving the data.

I am using this code:

```
if ($this->Login->validates(array('fieldList' => array('password','name')))) {
    if ($this->Login->save($this->data)) {
        echo 'helllo';exit;
        //$this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated.');
        //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'profile'));
    }else {

    }
} else {

}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You should properly do this by setting [`on` to `create` in the validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1145/One-Rule-Per-Field). Repeating this logic in the controller every time is bad.

The specific problem in your case is that `save` is validating *again*, and validating *all* fields. In fact, the first call the `validates` is entirely superfluous. You will have to use the third `$fieldlist` parameter of the `save` function if you only want to save/validate certain fields:

```
$this->Login->save($this->data, true, array('password','name'))
```

Comment: its because i am using primary key someid in place  of id .

Answer (score 0):

You better seperate everything, at first you validate, if everything goes ok, only then, save any data.

Validation should return some data, where it has failed, additionally, there are different data types, different things to check, for each field - there should be some classification for your site, what are limits, for specific field.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you only want the validation to apply on `create`, and not `update`. Cake has this functionality built in.

In your model, where each fields validation rules are, you will have something similar to:

```
var $validate = array(
    'fieldName1' => array(
        'rule' => 'ruleName', // or: array('ruleName', 'param1', 'param2' ...)
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'on' => 'create', // or: 'update'       ** here **
        'last' => false,
        'message' => 'Your Error Message'
    )
);
```

Might resolve your issue.